# Is there a more efficient O(n) algorithm to filter substring in a list?

Tags: python

For example, my string list 'items' store strings, like the following. I want to remove substrings if any is a substring of the other. So I first sort it:

```
items = ['df', 'gb', 'd', 'abc', 'def', 'ab',  'f', 'g']
items = sorted(items, key=len, reverse=True)
```

Then, I compare each shorter string with long strings and remove substring in two loops:

```
item_size = len(items)

filtered_items = set()
for i in range(item_size-1):
  current = items[i]
  for j in range(i+1,item_size):
    next = items[j]
    if next in current:
      filtered_items.add(next)
```

Finally, I do a set operation to get new string list:

```
new_items = set(items) - filtered_items

print(new_items)


# Expected resulting list
new_items = ['abc', 'def', 'df', 'gb']
```

I can't figure out a faster solution to solve this although I believe there must be such a solution.

Comment: The only additional optimization I can think of is that substrings are transitive: if x is in y, and y is in z, then x  is in z. I'm not sure how you can easily take advantage of this in your algorithm.

Comment: I feel there should be a better solution since this seems a typical need for many.

Comment: Is it really? It seems like a manufactured problem that mostly exists in coding contests. What is the real world use case?

Comment: And unless the lists are really long, the complexity isn't much of a concern.

Comment: It's a real problem, and I just use simple strings to illustrate the case. The  longest list could be up to 100 items, mostly shorter than that.

Comment: 100 items is nothing, even an O(n^3) algorithm would be fine.

Comment: Note: not an algorithmic optimization, but you can write this as a fairly straightforward list comprehension: `[x for x in items if not any(x != y and x in y for y in items)]` which yields `['df', 'gb', 'abc', 'def']`

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark I saw the solution, but I don't understand why the author's initial code doesn't err when it deletes items while iterating the list. Usually that will produce an error message.

Comment: @Chris Your code is much more concise and I like it. So in your code, the list doesn't have to be sorted so this would save some significant time. Right?

Comment: It's still iterating 64 times for a list of length 8, so it's O(n^2).

Comment: IIRC theres a solution for this involving a trie variant

Comment: If you are willing to store your data in something other than a list, there are [data structures that make this sort of thing more efficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substring_index). Getting the data into the structure may take more time than you save unless you are going to search over and over.